# Python Regex to get the first letter and the last word which matches a specific condition

Tags: python, regex

I have the following sentence and i am trying to extract the line that starts with 'R' and extract the word after the last space for those lines that start with R and then join the first letter and the last word.

```
text_raw = """
FIG
ITEM PART NUMBER NOMENCLATURE
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
EFFECT
FROM TO
PER
ASSY
1 
  ...SCREW- 102913 6600 XY14678-10
  STANDARD SUBSTITUTION:      
       JK784678-19     
       SDFG12HL3H8     
  ...PIN- 007999 8105 BHF343212WO
  ...PIN- 007999 8105 DF960-23H
  STANDARD SUBSTITUTION:      
            D89SJA
R ...SEAL-CHECK 007999 2110 NAS21134-10F             <<<<< this line
R     SUPPLIER CODE:      
R      D89SJA     
R     FUNCTIONAL DESCRIPTION:      
R      THE SWING CHECK VALVE IS     
R      TO LOCK AIR PREVENTION     
R      DUE FROM THE LEAK     
R      COMPARTMENT.       
      
  ...SCREW- 102913 6600 XY14678-10
  STANDARD SUBSTITUTION:      
       JK784678-19     
       SDFG12HL3H8     
  ...PIN- 007999 8105 BHF343212WO
  ...PIN- 007999 8105 DF960-23H
  STANDARD SUBSTITUTION:      
            D89SJA
R .PROFILE BLOCK ASSY-BRAKE    445 11W3421-30       <<<<< this line
R     SUPPLIER CODE:      
R      D89SJA     
R     FUNCTIONAL DESCRIPTION:      
R      THE BRAKE CHECK VALVE IS     
R      TO LOCK ANTI PREVENTION     
R      DUE FROM THE LEAK     
R      BRAKE.     
"""
```

I am able to get the lines that starts with R using the following code

```
body = []
part_no = []
regex = re.compile(r"R[\s\S]*$")
for line in text_raw.split('\n'):
  if regex.match(line):
    print(line)


R ...SEAL-CHECK 007999 2110 NAS21134-10F    
R     SUPPLIER CODE:      
R      D89SJA     
R     FUNCTIONAL DESCRIPTION:      
R      THE SWING CHECK VALVE IS     
R      TO LOCK AIR PREVENTION     
R      DUE FROM THE LEAK     
R      COMPARTMENT.       
R .PROFILE BLOCK ASSY-BRAKE    445 11W3421-30
R     SUPPLIER CODE:      
R      D89SJA     
R     FUNCTIONAL DESCRIPTION:      
R      THE BRAKE CHECK VALVE IS     
R      TO LOCK ANTI PREVENTION     
R      DUE FROM THE LEAK     
R      BRAKE.
```

and using this regex i am able to get the last word correctly

```
body_str = "\n".join(body)
last_word = re.findall(r"[^\s]+$", body_str, re.MULTILINE)

['NAS21134-10F', '11W3421-30']
```

What i am looking for is to take the first letter and join it with last word for those lines that fulfils both regex expressions : "[^\s]+$"  and  "[^\s]+$".
How can i get the following expected result?:

```
['R - NAS21134-10F', 'R - 11W3421-30']
```

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a single expression to get the 2 values, and then prepend `R -`  to capture group 1.

```
^R[^\S\r\n].*[^\S\r\n](\S+)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `R[^\S\r\n]` Match `R` and a space without a newline
- `.*[^\S\r\n]` Match the whole line, then the last space without a newline
- `(\S+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HfJqnq/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FlyMlk)

(Removing the comments from the example data)

```
for s in re.findall(r"^R[^\S\r\n].*[^\S\r\n](\S+)$", text_raw, re.MULTILINE):
    print (f"R - {s}")
```

Output

```
R - NAS21134-10F
R - 11W3421-30
```

---

Capturing either `R` `N` or `D`, you can use 2 capturing groups with a character class `([RND])`

```
for s in re.findall(r"^([RND])[^\S\r\n].*[^\S\r\n](\S+)$", text_raw, re.MULTILINE):
    print (f"{s[0]} - {s[1]}")
```

Comment: fourth bird, if i don't want to hard code the 'R' and take it dynamically from the first letter of the line, should i use a substring function and concatenate with the code you provided ?

Comment: @Samtech But you match the `R` in your example code as well right? If you want to match the first "letter" of the line, then you might use a character class `[A-Z]` instead of R to match an uppercase char. See https://regex101.com/r/cpUUF2/1

Comment: @fourth bird, actually i noticed the remaining text has R, N & D, i want to parse it in the same manner, either R|D|N, is that possible to do ? so thats why i wanted the first letter to be dynamic,so the regex would be ^[RDN][^\S\r\n].*[^\S\r\n](\S+)$, but how do i take the first letter then ?

Comment: Then you can use a character class to specifically match one of those 3 chars `^([RND])[^\S\r\n].*[^\S\r\n](\S+)$` https://regex101.com/r/xbsZS6/1

Comment: Thanks, this solves the regex pattern, would really appreciate your help to make it dynamic in selecting the first character in this line of code you provided 

for s in re.findall(r"^R[^\S\r\n].*[^\S\r\n](\S+)$", text_raw, re.MULTILINE):
    print (f"R - {s}")